# Find database in SQL Server Object Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-express, localdb

I am using VS2013 Express Web Edition and I have coded a C# MVC 5 Internet application, and wish to delete the database from the SQL Server Object Explorer.

Here is my connection string:

```
"Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CanFindLocation26.mdf;Initial Catalog=CanFindLocation26;Integrated Security=True"
```

I have opened up the SQL Server Object Explorer, yet cannot find my database.

There is a (localdb)\Projects node, that has a database node, yet my database is not there. There is also a Projects - CanFindLocation folder, with nothing in it. My MVC5 application name is CanFindLocation.

Where is my database in the SQL Server Object Explorer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Object Explorer will only list databases that have been formally mounted and attached to the server; as I understand it, ad-hoc files can also be mounted - but they don't show in the same way.

Comment: How is the best way to attach a database to SQL Express?

Comment: actually I see this is localdb, but it remains the same: if you intend referencing *files* (like in your example), then what you have is fine; if you want to reference *databases*, then: attach the database at the server (using sql commands or object explorer), and use the database name in the connection string, rather than a filename

Answer (score 0):

You have to build your database project then you cand find your database with tables in **sql server 
object explorer->SQL Server->Projects->Your database**

In your web application in web.config file connecting string should be automatically created.

Thanks